# Stack Gives Back total is off by $6 (...to 8)

Tags: support, status-completed, blog

In the blog that was just published: [Stack Gives Back 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/01/13/stack-gives-back-2021/) the total of the donations is off by 6. When adding up all the amounts mentioned per organisation the total comes to $55,694 instead of $55,700.

I know that usually the donation for mods that don't make a choice is divided between the organisations, which could lead to a small rounding error, but I find $6 a rather large error in this case.

Comment: It'ss supposed to be a hundred per moderator (55700 by 557 moderators), but some donations are rounder than others. It's not clear how the division of the remainder of the moderators that didn't reply happened.

Comment: The 6 dollars might be the total of transaction fees, but that's a guess at best.

Comment: Gave it a status-review, because the blog probably should either use correct numbers or have an explanation of why things don't add up ;)

Comment: It's also [off by 1](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) ... *Currently there are 558 moderators volunteering their time across the Stack Exchange network.* (of course, 'caching')

Comment: This should be migrated to Mathematica.SE :P

Comment: @SPArcheon not to Money.SE?

Comment: The Girls Who Code link is broken too, `href` is set to `http://$8,427 [Girls Who Code](https://www.girlswhocode.com/`

Comment: @JNat, what is status-deferred meaning in this case?

Comment: @Luuklag ... maybe deferred until a new calculator gets delivered?

Comment: I passed it along to someone who can fix this, @Luuklag, but since I haven't heard back from 'em yet, I decided to go with deferred instead of planned ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, I made a typo in the reported amounts on the blog post. Thanks for catching that! The mistake was with UNICEF which originally had $6,160 reported. The actual donated amount however, was $6,166, which has been verified with our finance team. This amount has been corrected on the blog post as well.

Comment: How did we end up with odd numbers like that anyway?

Comment: @Laurel: We surveyed all the mods about which of the selected charities they wanted their donation allocated to, but not all mods responded to the survey; the remaining amount allocated by the company for donations on behalf of those mods (who didn't respond) was equally divided among all the selected charities.

Comment: @V2Blast: Then each moderator who didn't respond should have had $20 donated in his or her name to each of the five charities; if I recall correctly, each who did respond should have had $100 donated in his or her name to just one of the five charities: the total donated to each charity should therefore be a multiple of $20, as in previous years.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica: Yeah, I realized that as well after another user pointed it out in a since-deleted comment. ...After doing some calculations, it looks like, for the donations on behalf of mods who didn't respond, we split their donations in proportions corresponding to how many of the mods who did respond chose each of those charities. (Juan can weigh in to confirm.)